# requirements and settings to be able to stream a larger video(20 minutes over 200 meg, mp4) on a ubuntu server running apache2, php5.4 and fastcgi?

Tags: apache2, video, php, streaming, mp4

I've got it working on smaller videos using owncloud , Ubuntu 14.04, apache2 fast CGI, etc. It works on a 1 minute video but if it is longer than 2 minutes it has to download the whole file before it streams. In php.INI I have set the cache to 2 gig, have set the mime types in apache2.conf. I tried installing the flv streamer but it still remains the same that small videos stream but larger ones have to wait to download. I have been searching hi and low through the forums for 3 weeks and googling without and any break throughs, can anyone suggest the right direction? Kind regards Michael

Answer (score 0):

Ref http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292901&p=13360326#post13360326

Re: Streaming Mp4 videos without having to download the whole file
I've gone full turn on this but I have an answer for apache2. 
History >>> I installed the xsendfile module and couldn't get it to work. I ended up dumping apache2 and going over to lighttpd with all the various mods to get it going. It would work for androids and windows but due to the headers not sending correctly it wouldn't work at all with IOS. Owncloud didn't like Lighttpd and spat out a heap of errors. I persevered but came to an end and went back to a snapshot I had with Apache2. I checked my error logs again and the issue was firmly pointed at xsendfile. I modified my settings for Xsendfile and got it working.

To get it working this is assuming you have a setup running with php and the fastcgi modules installed, etc. If you can get a video to play after it downloads the whole video first then this is for you!

Code:
apt-get install libapache2-mod-xsendfile
inside your server ssl file add the code
Code:

    ...
    SetEnv MOD_X_SENDFILE_ENABLED 1
    XSendFile On
    XSendFilePath /

Bear in mind to test it start with this >>>> XsendFilePath / <<<<<<<
When it works lock it down a little better say where the webserver data directory is. I messed around with this and I ended exposing the data directory where my files that would be served are kept. If someone has a better suggestion please update me!

I am able to stream video to all platforms now (IOS, Android and windows) but Windows XP setups don't work but that's the least of my worries.
You have to process each video with MMPEG - I tried a tonne of programs but ffmpeg seems to be the best.
Now I import my videos to my cloud and wrote a bash script to convert and send the converted to another directory on the cloud.
Run the ffmpeg line as suggested here - that does most videos, I ended up finding a different way of doing it for android mp4's.
Kind regards

Michael